# How do delete an empty column in an array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to delete EMPTY MULTIPLE COLUMNS in an array obtained with `getRange (row, column, numRows, numColumns)`? My table is quite large so I cannot use `deleteColumn (columnPosition)` otherwise go back to the server column after column.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior using the Advanced Google Services.
To activate it go to `Resources>Advanced Google Services...>Google Sheets API` and turn on the corresponding switch.

You can batch the delete requests so that the communication with the server will occur only once. 
You will have to arrange the ranges you want to delete according to the DimensionRange Class:

```js
"range": {
   "sheetId": integer,
   "dimension": enum (Dimension), //ROWS or COLUMNS
   "startIndex": integer,
   "endIndex": integer
}
```

Each new range object obtained by your filter logic should then be used as a deleteDimension request Object.
Simply create as many as deleteDimension object you need and append them to an array:

```js
let request = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
request.requests = [
    {
     "deleteDimension": {
      "range": { // Example representing the 1st column
         "sheetId": 0,
         "dimension": 'COLUMNS', //ROWS or COLUMNS
         "startIndex": 1,
         "endIndex": 2
      }
     }
    }, 
    {
     "deleteDimension": {
      ...
    }
   }
];
```

Now use this batch request in the corresponding method to execute the request for the wanted Spreadsheet:

```js
let response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request, spreadsheet_id);
```

### References:

[BatchUpdate request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

[DeleteDimension](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)

Comment: Thank you very much Alessandro but your solution is little bit complicated for my level. I was thinking about doing this with arrays if it is possible ?

Comment: This is the only way to use batch operations with Apps Script. Otherwise you will need to call `deleteColumn()` for each column, and this will result in a lot of networking overhead.  It is using a JSON array though. You can build it in a for loop as you are filtering the empty columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach which involves using *getRange (row, column, numRows, numColumns)* and arrays as requested.

```js
function removeEmptyCols() {
    // get active sheet
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    /*
    you said you were using getRange (row, column, numRows, numColumns)
    get data range from my test active sheet - from row 2 (to ignore heading), column 1, 50 rows, 15 columns
    */
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,50,15);
    //assign the cell values to a 2D array
    var rangeValues = range.getValues();
    // get number of rows
    var numRows = rangeValues.length;
    //get number of columns
    var numCols = rangeValues[0].length;
    // declare array of empty columns to remove at the end
    var colsToDelete = [];
    // loop through columns 
    for(var i=0; i < numCols; i++) {
        // loop through each row
        for (var j=0; j < numRows; j++) {
            if (!rangeValues[j][i]) {
               // cell is empty, keep calm and carry on
               if (j = numRows) {
                 /*
                 this is the last row so we know the column is empty
                 record empty column number to delete in array
                 */
                 colsToDelete.push(i);
               }
            } else {
              // cell has value so break as column can't then be empty
              break;
            }      
        }  
    }
    var numColsToDelete = colsToDelete.length;
    /*
    if you wanted to delete the columns directly in the spreadsheet...
    remove comment from two lines in for loop
    working backwards to preserve column position as they are deleted
    */
    for (var k = numColsToDelete; k > 0; k--) {
      // var col = colsToDelete[k-1];
      // sheet.deleteColumn(col+1); 
    }
    
    // otherwise
    
    // removing the 'columns' from the rangeValues 2D array...
    for (var l=0; l < numRows; l++) {
      // working backwards to preserve array index position
      for (var m = numColsToDelete; m > 0; m--) {
        var col = colsToDelete[m-1];
        rangeValues[l].splice(col,1);
      }        
    }
 
    /* 
    then you could do with rangeValues what you wanted
    like copying it to a new sheet...
    */
    var newNumCols = numCols - numColsToDelete;
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet().activate();
    newSheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,newNumCols).setValues(rangeValues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.